# Tesseract OCR, extract dark box from image / finding y-coordinate to text at

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

For pre-processing, I need to crop out any pixels that are not in the [dark box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tAfj.png).

The intent is to crop out [just the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iPZe.png).

Finally, I do additional processing to turn it into a [black and white image perfect for Tesseract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHBAa.png).

Unfortunately, I've been finding it difficult to find the y-coordinate to crop at.

I've tried:

- Adding in contours to find the box (either too many lines or cannot detect the end of the dark box) - [contour lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NLDl.png)
- Using template matching to find the last margin in the image (fails when the background is different) - [working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lxlv.png) - [failing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diMia.png)
- Increasing saturation/brightness - [doesn't help isolate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUg8f.png)
- Process extraneous text instead of trying to crop image – unfortunately the extra image data often seems to ruin the accuracy of the text that I want

Assumptions:

- The image width, font, line-spacing, and margins is always the same.
- The number of lines of text will vary.
- The last line of the text will vary.
- The background will often be different.

Here are some other images that I would want the algorithm to work with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhBQv.jpg

Thank you in advance!